# Query to populate viewmodel object with single properties and list of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling to write a query to populate a viewmodel which consists of some single properties and a list of objects.

These are my entity models:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public List<ProductInCategory> ProductInCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int NumOfProducts { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This is how far I've gotten on my query to populate the viewmodel before returning it to the view:

```
var VMCategory = (from Category in _context.ProductCategories
  join ProdInCat in _context.ProductsInCategories
  on Category.Id equals ProdInCat.ProductCategoryId
  join Product in _context.Products
  on ProdInCat.ProductId equals Product.Id
  select new ViewModelProductCategory
  {
      Id = Category.Id,
      ParentId = Category.ParentId,
      Title = Category.Title,
      SortOrder = Category.SortOrder,
      NumOfProducts = ... // Perhaps count something?
      Products = ... // A list of products
  }).ToList();
```

This image illustrates how I'm expecting the result of the query to look like:
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something as simple as this:

```
var products = _context.ProductCategories
    .Select(category => new ViewModelProductCategory
    {
        Id = category.Id,
        ParentId = category.ParentId,
        Title = category.Title,
        SortOrder = category.SortOrder,
        NumOfProducts = category.ProductInCategory.Count()
        Products = category.ProductInCategory
            .Select(pic => new ViewModelProduct
            {
                Id = pic.Product.Id,
                Title = pic.Product.Title,
                Price = pic.Product.Price,
                Info = pic.Product.Info
            }
            .ToList();
    }).ToList();
```

You could keep the query syntax, though, I find it more readable this way.

This assumes there's a navigational property in `ProductInCategory` pointing to `Product` (which was not added to the question) defined as follows:

```
public Product Product { get; set; }
```